# lwjgl + slick2d + jinput error on 64-bit linux

Tags: lwjgl, slick2d, jinput

I am using Linux (Ubuntu 12.04) with 64-bit java 7 and Eclipse (Indigo).
On the game project we are using slick2d and along with it lwjgl. I was halted by the following errors.
(fixes explained in the answer)

1. java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no lwjgl in java.library.path
2. java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no jinput-linux64 in java.library.path
3. Failed to open device (/dev/input/event8): Failed to open device /dev/input/event8

Versions:

Slick2D

Mon, 01 Oct 2012 09:54:11 +0100
Sun May 11 20:17:03 BST 2008
build=264

LWJGL (could be 2.8.5 already, but now this):

2.8.4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. To fix this, follow the instructions provided in the 'slick2d' documentation

   ## http://www.slick2d.org/wiki/index.php/Main_Page
2. This seems to be a real bug with slick2D/lwjgl on the versions that we are currently using. To fix this you can't use 64-bit java (with linux at least). Download the 32-bit java from Oracle web site and configure this to be your IDEs runtime environment (you may need to search for more help how to do this in your particular IDE)
3. This is purely related to permissions on linux. Go to '/dev/input' and change the folder permission 'sudo chmod 644 *' so that the process can simply read what's in there.

There didn't seem to be info on how to fix this problem whole together. Hope this helps some one else.

Comment: Just a later note: We dropped the slick 2D all together and refactored the code to use LibGdx. Slick2D has more sophisticated way of handling things in Java way, but constant problems with the environment was enough. The most important was that the repository to load the library was constantly down or changed location. Not sure if this project is even alive anymore? (it said somewhere that the project has been terminated, but there seems to be wiki and such pages still for it)

Answer (score 0):

Download [slick](http://slick.ninjacave.com/) and copy needed libs (jinput-linux64, lwjgl, **.dll** & **.so** files) to  your **java.library.path**

to get the **java.library.path** you can do so: `System.out.println(System.getProperty("java.library.path"));`